# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - Kotlin

Tags: hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I have a project where using `kotlin` `hibernate` together, my problem is I get a `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy` when I trying to reach one entities `Lazy` fetched related field. I put `@Transactional` to the service method which calls the repository method.

If I put `Hibernate.initialize(download.content)` to the service it works fine, but I want to avoid this. And I dont to set the entity field `Eager`.

My entities:

```
@Entity
class Download(
        user: User,
        subject: String,
        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL]) 
        @JoinColumn(name = "content_id", referencedColumnName = "id") val content: ActionContent
) : Action(user, subject)

@Entity
class ActionContent (
        @Lob val content: String,
        @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null
)
```

Is anybody who have experienced the same problem?

Comment: There are two options. 1. Define an EntityGraph 2. Use JOIN FETCH how does your repository look like

Comment: I added the JOIN FETCH part to my query and now it works. I thought `@Transactional` will do this.

Comment: Great. I'm happy to help. I add this as the answer. Can you please accept it as the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options.

1. Define an EntityGraph
2. Use JOIN FETCH in your query

Both will trigger the loading of the lazy loaded realtionships